# I get a dead blank window after closing excel 2016?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

My codes run fine until I get to closing the workbook. Here's my code:

```
.....
    With olMail
        .Subject = "Hi " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        .Body = strSubject
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        .display
    End With
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNameSpace = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    DoEvents
    ActiveWorkbook.Close <<<<===== I see the BLANK EXCEL WINDOW HERE!
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug with excel 2016 or not but this is the whole window of excel, it is missing the ribbon:

[image]

Comment: What is your error ? if you have your Excel.Application still running, and only 1 Workbook (your `ActiveWorkbook`) and you close it, then you are left with Excel application running, without any Workbooks open. You can replace all your code line at the end with `ActiveWorkbook.Close True`

Comment: I don't really have an error in the code, excel just shows me this blank window when closing the workbook. If i open up another excel workbook, it will open in this blank window and works fine. I'm just wondering why excel would look like this when closing when shouldn't it still show the ribbon and the minimize and maximize stuff.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the ribbon crashing? I have an add in that runs macro ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you close the workbook and not the application.

Use `Application.Quit`

Comment: Yes i understand that but when you close a workbook, shouldn't you have the minimize and maximize and the ribbon still in tack?

Comment: Interesting I am running a few combinations trying to recreate the issue but my ribbon is still in tact. I am however  using 2010 at my work. Ill try 2016 when I get home though if someone hasnt already provided a sufficient answer.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the ribbon crashing? I have an add in that runs macro ect.